# how to send http request c#

Tags: httpwebrequest, load-balancing, web-farm

we have web farm architecture. Load balancer is maintaining all the requests. I want to send a http request to the server of my choice. But i am unable to do so because of load balancer. I am doing this in a windows application. Could you please suggest ways to bypass load balancer?

Thanks
AR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your data to the IP of the server and not the loadbalencer. That means that I expect that the server itself is reachable from the web and not only via the loadbalancer.

Comment: HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);          I am sending httprequest in this way. How can i specify server IP here.. Create method isn't taking argument IP Address. . is there any other method that i can try??.. thanks

Comment: Well behind `example.com` is a (range of) IP(s) where the `WebRequest` will connect with, so if you specify the IP of the target server instad of the IP (or hostname) you will connect to the right server.

Comment: It made me embarrassed... How did i not even think and asked such a stupid question?. Anyway, Thanks man...

Comment: Don't worry. That can happen ;-)